# View Transparency issue in ios7 while presenting modalViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am having an app in which I am using **presentViewController** for navigating from one view to another.

I have a view controller in which I have set the background color of view to clear color.

In my **XIB**, I have one view with the height of 200 pixels, while presenting this view, I want only this view to be shown, the rest of the portion should be transparent.

For that I am using the below code.

```
view.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
```

This works fine above ios7 but not for ios7.

I have searched a lot but none of those worked for me.

Please help me on this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

From [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18661)'s Forum link,
You need to Present Viewcontroller like ,

**Before iOS 8, you do this:**

```
[backgroundViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
[backgroundViewController presentViewController:_myMoreAppsViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**in iOS 8, you have to do this:**

```
backgroundViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
backgroundController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[overlayViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
```

Set your controller in-place of backgroundViewController.
I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking view in XIB, use view controller in story board with 200 pixel of view, then change presentation in storyboard to "Over current content" will give you full transparent effect, except that 200 pixel portion, Here is the images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZW6U.png

Present Model this view controller using segue.